# Elastic Search - is there a way to force documents in results that may match "must_not" criteria?

Tags: elasticsearch

We run a very large data set of articles. We do our searches based on certain keyword, filters, ranges etc. Our queries contain the `MUST/SHOULD/MUST_NOT/FILTER` structure.

We need to be able to force certain results to show that would otherwise match `MUST_NOT` criteria.

Is there a way to force document ids into the query that would trump/override the `MUST_NOT` clauses? Or is `MUST_NOT` king in Elastic Search regardless.

We've tried nested bool queries in each `MUST/SHOULD` to force the document id into the results, but nothing. The example below has it in the `SHOULD` block.

We've tried forcing the document ID into the `MUST` block, with no further match_phrase etc, but the `MUST_NOT` criteria still trumps the `MUST` and no results return.

Here is an example of a query. I have removed aggregations for simplicity.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [],
            "should": [
              {
                "multi_match": {
                  "query": "Italy",
                  "fields": [
                    "title",
                    "content^2",
                    "tags"
                  ],
                  "analyzer": "standard",
                  "boost": 1
                }
              },
              {
                "query_string": {
                  "fields": [
                    "tags"
                  ],
                  "query": "*Italy*",
                  "default_operator": "AND",
                  "minimum_should_match": 1
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "Serie A",
            "fields": [
              "title",
              "content^2",
              "tags"
            ],
            "type": "phrase",
            "boost": 4
          }
        },
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "football",
            "fields": [
              "title",
              "content^2",
              "tags"
            ],
            "boost": 3
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "_id": [
              "5.4416039680717e+23"
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "content": "Cristiano Ronaldo"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "source.feed.editorialTopics": "AmericanFootball"
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1,
      "boost": 1
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 20
}
```

In this case, we are looking for documents that reference the Italian Serie A but exclude all documents that include `Cristiano Ronaldo` in the content except for one document ID: `5.4416039680717e+23` which must be included even though it DOES contain `Cristiano Ronaldo` in the content.

The result does not return that document ID ever.

What are we doing wrong? Or is there no way to do this in Elastic Search?

Comment: What version of elasticsearch are you using?

Comment: We are running Elasticsearch 6.5 on AWS.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way in order to not interfere with your current query logic is wrap everything with a should clause. Something like this

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        { // --> your current query
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "bool": {
                  "should": [
                    {
                      "multi_match": {
                        "query": "Italy",
                        "fields": [
                          "title",
                          "content^2",
                          "tags"
                        ],
                        "analyzer": "standard",
                        "boost": 1
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "query_string": {
                        "fields": [
                          "tags"
                        ],
                        "query": "*Italy*",
                        "default_operator": "AND",
                        "minimum_should_match": 1
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ],
            "should": [
              {
                "multi_match": {
                  "query": "Serie A",
                  "fields": [
                    "title",
                    "content^2",
                    "tags"
                  ],
                  "type": "phrase",
                  "boost": 4
                }
              },
              {
                "multi_match": {
                  "query": "football",
                  "fields": [
                    "title",
                    "content^2",
                    "tags"
                  ],
                  "boost": 3
                }
              },
              {
                "terms": {
                  "_id": [
                    "5.4416039680717e+23"
                  ]
                }
              }
            ],
            "must_not": [
              {
                "match_phrase": {
                  "content": "Cristiano Ronaldo"
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "source.feed.editorialTopics": "AmericanFootball"
                }
              }
            ],
            "minimum_should_match": 1,
            "boost": 1
          }
        },
        { // --> the extra logic (else)
          "must": {
            "match_phrase": {
              "content": "Cristiano Ronaldo"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 20
}
```

Basically if you have a query full of logic and you want to say:
`bring me the results that match either this big query or this smaller one`. Minimum should match is by default 1 when nothing else (must, must_not) is present.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work ... Even restructuring my query to follow your suggestion did not pull the document ID filtered out by the MUST_NOT criteria. No matter where i put the

```
{
                "terms": {
                  "_id": [
                    "5.4416039680717e+23"
                  ]
                }
              }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do this by putting your must_not and your ID query into a should clause with minimum_should_match 1:

```
"should": [
    {
        "must_not": [
            {
                "match_phrase": {
                    "content": "Cristiano Ronaldo"
                }
            },
            {
                "match": {
                    "source.feed.editorialTopics": "AmericanFootball"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "terms": {
            "_id": [
                "5.4416039680717e+23"
            ]
        }
    },
],
"minimum_should_match": 1,
```

This means you if either of them match, your document will return. You mave have to juggle this around a bit to not interfere with your other should clause (e.g. by using a nested bool query?), but the principle should work